# Can I sell an iPhone app that contains the audio generated by Mac OSX "say" command?

Tags: iphone, macos, audio

If I use the Mac OSX "say" command to produce audio files containing words or phrases, can I include them in an iPhone app and sell that app? Are there any license implications?

Comment: You may want to consider reposting this elsewhere. It's not *really* a programming question. More of a copyright issue.

Comment: Could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Apple's Developer Forums would be a better place to ask.